# Which site can I ask about the different flavors of Windows OS?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask questions about the different flavors of Windows OS but am not sure which site is best. Super User, Server Fault, Stack Overflow, other?

Comment: As vague as this question?

Comment: What kinds of questions exactly? Can you make an example?

Comment: this was a meta question. the actual question could have been: what is the difference in cost between XP and Windows 7 for single user?  But as this is meta, not specific, I was looking to learn the correct forum, NOT to ask the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super User of course. But you need to be a little more precise in your question. Or else you would end up referred to microsoft site, where they do comparison.

If you narrow your question to for example: how does the different version of windows handle XXX
you may find help on Super User.

Comment: thank you, the actual question will be more specific, just wanted to know which forum to start in

Answer (score 1):

Well, a question about "flavors of Windows OSs" probably will not be about server issues, so don't ask on Server Fault. It's probably some kind of comparison of the flavors, which is probably not going to be a Stack Overflow question.

I suggest Super User, as that is the home for people who are "users" of systems, software, and hardware.

Comment: unless it's a comparison of the flavors of Server OS ... then it would be valid for server fault, but if it's a vague as this then ... well it doesn't belong anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

### When did Windows start coming in different flavors?  I thought it was a flavor...

If your talking about WMI-defined flags that describes the behavior of a qualifier  then SO is the place to ask.